# Need help with the following error..the method is there but still getting this error

Tags: c#

> 'Main.mainClass' does not contain a
>   definition for 'myMethod' and no
>   extension method 'myMethod' accepting
>   a first argument of type
>   'Main.mainClass' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Comment: Posting your code might help!
Try Clean and Rebuild..

Comment: 1. Post the Code. 2. Please, don't include "C#.net Beginner ques" in your question title, it does not help anyone and is actually waste of space making it hard to read the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using referance to call that method.If yes, try to build just your project which contains that method, then rebuild solution. This problem occurs sometimes, when your build order fails.

We need more details to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you have a static Main method and your "myMethod" is not static, in this case you should make either "myMethod" static or get an instance of mainClass.

```
class mainClass
{

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
mainClass main = new mainClass();
main.myMethod();
}

public void myMethod()
{
  //Stuff here
}
}
```

or:

```
class mainClass
{

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  myMethod();
}

public static void myMethod()
{
  //Stuff here
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without showing us your code it's impossible to tell exactly what the problem is but I would bet on one of these:

- You are trying to access a static method using a member instance or the other way around
- You have implemented a method with the same name but it has different parameters
- You have made your method private and try to access it from another class
- You tried to call a member method on `yourObj` like `myMethod(yourObj)` instead of `yourObj.myMethod()`